# SQL - full outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

i have three table in sql database

[image]

i need to join this three table to get table like this

[image]

I want to join three table to get all  data from whole first, third and second (where sort is 2)  table

I try this query

```
  select table1.Item, table1.Location, table1.Type,
         table2.Item, table2.Location, table2.Type,table2.Sort
         table3.Item, table3.Location, table3.Type
   from table1
 full outer join table2
  on table1.Item = table2.Item
  and table1.Location = table2.Location
  and table1.Type = table2.Type
  and table2.Sort = '2'
 full outer join table3
  on table1.Item = table3.Item
  and table1.Location = table3.Location
  and table1.Type = table3.Type
```

but i only get this table

[image]

How to make query to get table i want with all combination?

Any idea?

Comment: Which RDMS are you on?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Comment: can you please post your tables and code as formatted text instead of images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select table1.Item, table1.Location, table1.Type,
       table2.Item, table2.Location, table2.Type, table2.Sort,
       table3.Item, table3.Location, table3.Type
from table1
  full outer join table3
    on  table1.Item = table3.Item
   and table1.Location = table3.Location
   and table1.Type = table3.Type
  full outer join table2
    on (table1.Item = table2.Item
   and table1.Location = table2.Location
   and table1.Type = table2.Type
   and table2.Sort = '2'
   )
   or (table3.Item = table2.Item
   and table3.Location = table2.Location
   and table3.Type = table2.Type
   and table2.Sort = '2'
   )
where (table2.Sort = '2' or table2.Sort is null)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MNW25175

results

```
+------+----------+-------+------+----------+-------+------+------+----------+-------+
| Item | Location | Type  | Item | Location | Type  | Sort | Item | Location | Type  |
+------+----------+-------+------+----------+-------+------+------+----------+-------+
| 123  | A        | small | NULL | NULL     | NULL  | NULL | 123  | A        | small |
| NULL | NULL     | NULL  | 123  | A        | big   | 2    | 123  | A        | big   |
| NULL | NULL     | NULL  | 123  | B        | small | 2    | NULL | NULL     | NULL  |
+------+----------+-------+------+----------+-------+------+------+----------+-------+
```

---

This also works, but only because `table2` has a match for all rows in `table1`, which might not fit your actual use case:

```
select table1.Item, table1.Location, table1.Type,
       table2.Item, table2.Location, table2.Type, table2.Sort,
       table3.Item, table3.Location, table3.Type
from table1
  full outer join table3
    on  table1.Item = table3.Item
   and table1.Location = table3.Location
   and table1.Type = table3.Type
  full outer join table2
    on table3.Item = table2.Item
   and table3.Location = table2.Location
   and table3.Type = table2.Type
   and table2.Sort = '2'
where (table2.Sort = '2' or table2.Sort is null)
```

Comment: Thaks a lot .. :)

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is correct, all you're missing is using `coalesce` in your second join criterias.

The first `outer join` will return you a set of rows with some `null` values in it, and if you use those values in the third `join` criterias, the condition won't be satisfied.

You can solve this problem using `coalesce`, that will use the second parameter if the first one is `null`

```
select  table1.Item, table1.Location, table1.Type,
        table2.Item, table2.Location, table2.Type,table2.Sort
        table3.Item, table3.Location, table3.Type
from    table1
full outer join table2
on      table1.Item = table2.Item and
        table1.Location = table2.Location and
        table1.Type = table2.Type
full outer join table3
on      coalesce(table1.Item, table2.Item) = table3.Item and
        coalesce(table1.Location, table2.Location) = table3.Location and
        coalesce(table1.Type, table2.Type) = table3.Type
where   coalesce(table2.Sort, 2) = 2
```

Comment: I think you'd need to add `where  coalesce(table2.Sort, '2') = '2'`, otherwise you might get other `Sort` values in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Use LEFT OUTER JOIN :

```
 SELECT *  FROM Table 2 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table 1 ON table1.Item = table2.Item AND  table1.Location =  
                  table2.Location AND table1.Type = table2.Type and 
                  table2.Sort = '2'
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table 3 ON table1.Item = table3.Item
                 and table1.Location = table3.Location
                 and table1.Type = table3.Type
```

Comment: But i can get more data in third table than second... this code than not work :(

Comment: But you have more rows in table 2 than table 3.

Answer (score 1):

You get the required result by the below query

```
SELECT d.item, d.location, d.[type],
    s.item, s.location, s.[type], s.sort,
    h.item, h.location, h.[type]
FROM tblData d
    FULL OUTER JOIN tblSearchData s
        ON d.item = s.item 
        AND d.location = s.location
        AND d.[type] = s.[type]
    FULL OUTER JOIN tblHelpData h
        ON (s.item = h.item OR d.item=h.item)
        AND (s.location = h.location OR d.location=h.location)
        AND (s.[type] = h.[type] OR d.[type]=h.[type])
WHERE s.sort=2 OR s.sort IS NULL
```